# string.lower() in an if loop doesn't lower case the string in Python?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, conditional-statements, lowercase

```
def translate(phrase):
    translation= ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter.lower() in "aeiou":
            if letter.isupper():
                translation = translation + "G"
            else:
                translation = translation + "g"

        else:
            translation = translation + letter
    return translation

print(translate(input("Enter a phrase: ")))
```

(This is a program to change vowels to the letter 'g' or 'G' depending if it is upper or lower case)

Why does this work? Since there is a letter.lower() shouldn't it transform that letter to a lowercase one? that way the next if statement ("if letter.isupper():") would never be true...

I'm confused because I only know C and I'm trying to learn Python. In C if I did that it would transform the letter variable to a lower case one so the next if statement would never be true. I'm guessing that functions inside if statements in Python don't change/alter the variables inside those same fucntions...? But then again that wouldn't really make sense to me... What am I thinking wrong?

Comment: You should try to focus on forming a solid question instead of trying to make sense of this code.  It is very hard to follow your thought process instead of answering a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower:

> Return a copy of the string with all the cased characters converted to lowercase.

`letter.lower()` does not modify `letter` when called, it returns a new value.